# How to create a static Map in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I would like to create a static Map which will contain key value pairs which are of both strings. This key value pair is never going to change.

Something like follows:

```
static KEY_VALUE_PAIR: Map<string, string>: {
 'space' : 'jump',
 'enter' : 'hit'
}
```

When I do this, I get an error saying `Type '{ 'space': string; }' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, string>'.` Am I doing something wrong here?

If I remove the return type `Map<string, string>`, it's a plain object and it works fine.

Comment: That's not a `Map`; you need to use `new Map()` to construct a map, just like in Javascript. If you want to use a Javascript object as something like a map, write `Record<string, string>` instead.

Comment: `{ space: 'jump', enter: 'hit' }` is a plain JavaScript object while `Map` is a completely different thing. Read about [objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and about [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in the [JavaScript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/).

Comment: Uh oh! @axiac @kaya3 Now I see the problem! `Record<string, string>` makes absolute sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A static map in Typescript can be created and initialized inline by creating a new [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object like this:

```js
const KEY_VALUE_PAIR = new Map<string, string>([
  ['space','jump'],
  ['enter','hit']
]);
```